# change alignment of \lfoot and \cfoot in latex with \fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I am using `\pagestyle{fancy}` and am trying to align the `\lfoot` and `\cfoot` sections of a page.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\makeatletter
\usepackage[letterpaper,top=1.in,left=0.4in,right=0.4in]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}

\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
\lfoot{\includegraphics[scale=0.22]{fakelogo}}
\cfoot{Footer \\ more footer}
\rfoot{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhfoffset[LH]{\oddsidemargin + \hoffset + 0.5in}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]


\end{document}
```

This results in the resulting output

[image: footer]

Based on my reading of the `fancyhdr` documentation and geometry, I've tried messing with `\footskip` and `\fancyhfoffset` but they all seem to move both the `\cfoot` and the `\lfoot`, and keep them non-centered. Any ideas?

Comment: So you want them to be vertically centred?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not specifying. I'd like the logo (lfoot) to be aligned with the center of the text (cfoot).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can raise (or lower) the contents of `\lfoot` and `\cfoot` into position, or do the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,lipsum}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} % Clear header/footer
\fancyfoot[L]{\includegraphics[scale=0.22,valign=c]{example-image}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}Footer \\ more footer\end{tabular}}

%\setlength{\footskip}{60pt}% Depends on image size

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

The image is assigned a `v`ertical `align`ment that is `c`entred, while `\cfoot` is placed inside a `tabular`. Without specifying the `tabular` vertical alignment, it defaults to being `c`entred.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. That worked perfectly (and a great write-up of the solution to boot).